# Unity - OnBeginDrag / OnDrag e.t.c not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to get the following code to work:

```
public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (item.ID != -1)
    {
        transform.position = eventData.position;
    }

}
```

Ignore item.ID != -1, I know for sure that's not the issue because it doesn't work no matter what the condition.

What I need to know is if there is a setting in the canvas or in the image (this script is attached to an image inside a panel) that needs to be enabled to get interaction to work. I could've sworn there was something that needs to be enabled to get the mouse working with the canvas.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLVED: Needed to add a Graphic Raycaster.

Comment: Congrats on figuring it out. I remember having a related issue a few weeks ago.  I'd have edited your answer to have some more deteal, but really...that's about all it needs. The graphic raycaster is what makes a canvas HAVE mouse input. Just be aware that having two active raycasters overlapping each other will cause events to fire on BOTH.