# Implement OnBeginDrag, OnDrag, etc. callback on Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a camera controller on a scene with a simple cube object.

I'm having problem on catching the touch events on android.

What's the simplest way to do this?

I've tried this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html

This is what I did so far:

- added a raycaster on the main camera
- added an event trigger on the cube
- applied the script on the cube

  ```
  EventTrigger trigger = GetComponent<EventTrigger>();
  EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
  entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.Drag;
  entry.callback.AddListener((data) => {
     OnDragDelegate((PointerEventData)data); 
  });
  trigger.triggers.Add(entry);
  ...
  public void OnDragDelegate(PointerEventData data)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to use DragHandler interfaces :

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Drag: MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print("OnBeginDrag");
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print("OnDrag");        
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print("OnEndDrag");        
    }
}
```

In this way not only it works in Android, but also you can test it in Unity Editor.

Comment: I already tried this but the callbacks doesn't trigger.

Here's a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457145/unity-onbegindrag-ondrag-e-t-c-not-working

Is there other way to add a Graphic Raycaster?

Comment: @user2034438 Make sure you have a `EventSystems` in the scene.

Comment: @zwcloud Thank you. I'll try this later and update you. Is this codewise? Or do I have to add this on the object list, like the raycaster. Sorry if I don't make any sense right now. I don't have unity in my machine right now.

Comment: @user2034438 In Hierarchy window, Right click and in UI, select EventSystem. The EventSystem is responsible for processing and handling events in a Unity Scene. A Scene should only contain one EventSystem.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html Create an empty GameObject and add component `EventSystem` to it.